# Debugging a C++ Application Crash

Tags: c++, boost, crash

Using Boost and OpenSSL Integration I am creating an application similar to a browser.

Somehow the program crashes before even it enters main() method.

Certainly, If the program utilizes DLLs they can be loaded before main() starts. The DllMain functions of those DLLs will be executed before main(). If they encounter an error they could cause the entire process to halt or crash.

How can one debug this scenario ?

Comment: Are you sure it's not your static variables that are causing harm?

Comment: Does it crash in release or debug mode? What does the stack trace or output log says in debug?

Comment: I have not used any static variables @GillBates

Comment: Release Mode (I would like to know what difference it create ?) How do I get the stack trace? Using makefile+cygwin+windows. @MarcoA.

Comment: @Milind Then use gdb to get a stack trace

Comment: I have tried GDB with Code Blocks and VC but not with makefile environment. @MarcoA.

Comment: I used Dependency Walker and found some DLLs were not found, so I'll try importing them first.